# TOEFL exam score report

Tags: formality

I registered for the TOEFL exam two months ago. With the TOEFL exam, a examinee can send score reports to up to four universities. But my question is, what's the deadline for adding the universities to the list?  I heard that it's three days before the exam. Is that right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the administration of a standardized exam, not about learning the English language itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For questions like this, it's best to go straight to the source.  At the time of this writing, the [ETS website for the TOEFL](http://www.ets.org/toefl/ibt/scores/send/) says the following:

> Score report recipients can be added or deleted through the TOEFL iBT® online registration system **until 10 p.m. (local test center time) on the day prior to the test date.** For selections made after the 10 p.m. deadline, there is a fee of US$18 for each score report requested. Score recipients cannot be changed or deleted after the 10 p.m. deadline. *(emphasis added)*

So you can add them the day before the test until 10 PM local test center time, or afterwards if you're willing to pay a US$18 fee.